# TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys I get the error

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

when I run the code below. I have just started to learn python

```
number = input('Type in a number between 5 and 20 - ')
# run loop as long as the number is more than 0
while number > 0:
    print('Number: ', number)
    number -= 1
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

do this:

```
number = int(input('Type in a number between 5 and 20 - '))
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, strings and numbers can't be compared directly, because in order to do so either the string would need to be converted to a number or the number to a string. Python doesn't try to guess which one would be correct (and in fact, converting a non-numeric string to a number would cause an error the interpreter wouldn't know how to handle).

`input` returns a string. You'll need to convert this string to an integer yourself using the `int` function to compare it to 0

Answer (score 1):

`input` is returning a string so when you enter for example '3', you are then doing a comparison like

```
while '3' > 0:
    pass
```

This is the cause of your error, since a string and an int are not comparable for a greater than operation. To fix it convert your input value to an `int`.

Like so

```
number = int(input('Type in a number between 5 and 20 - '))
```

Note that this will raise an exception if the string is not convertible to an integer value. You might want to catch that exception and print an error message, otherwise your script will just exit.

Comment: Thanks for you help everyone. What you guys would call a school boy error :0)

Comment: Easily done, especially as this may work in Python 2.